# Making the ASK QUESTION more prominent &c

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

- For a site whole purpose in life is to allow people to ask questions and answer them, the new design does not make the two corresponding 'links' prominent at all!
- Moreover, I really think it is quite not apparent that the "QUESTIONS TAGS USERS..." thingies under the header are active (you *can* hover over them, and then the thin font with which by browser renders then becomes #90191C: this is too subtle IMHO. Before it was way more obvious that something would happen upon clicking them: now, they look like a subtitle, specially because they match the all-caps style of the header (I guess one cannot assume real small caps are available?)
- The votes/answer counts are horizontally distributed in the parent site and vertically distributed on the meta site, but this seems to change every few reloads. The effect is weird :) The ayout is vertical but different in the QUESTIONS and UNANSWERED pages.
- Can it be ASK A QUESTION?

Comment: I use stackexchange sites everyday, in this one I hanged on finding how to ask a question!

Comment: +1 for ASK A QUESTION.

Answer (score 3):

I support making "ask question" a different color.

However.

It's sort of a myth in the Q&A world that you *want* to make it so easy for newbies to ask questions. This logic leads directly to things like http://yahooanswerfail.com

What you do want to do is make it easy for people to browse around -- and they have to work a teeny-tiny bit to find out how to ask. If they're not willing to put in the tiniest amount of work, the odds of that user asking a question you as an expert would *want* to answer is vanishingly small.

Comment: This was going to be about the &c in the title, not the ASK QUESTION, but when I tried to ask this I could not find the link... I want it to be easy for *me*. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

I have bolded the Ask Question link, also gave it a different link color. The change will be in the next deployment.